# How to get file extension from bytes[]

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I'm working on a `c#` project, I created a method that will receive a file as bytes value `byte[] parameter`.

**Method**

```
public static FileEncryptionModel Encrypt(byte[] Filebytes)
{
       //Some code here
}
```

the question is **how can I know the file extension just from its bytes?**
thank you.

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Do you know at least in general what these bytes are? Is it an image, video, text, or what?

Comment: Sometimes you can use the start signature to determine the content.

Comment: the problem I can't know what bytes file is, cause this method will receive all files types content as bytes[]

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85054/guessing-a-file-type-based-on-its-content and https://github.com/0xbrock/FileTypeChecker

Answer (score 4):

There is no foolproof way to achieve this. Take a look at the list of file signatures here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

As mentioned here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number

> Originally, this term was used for a specific set of 2-byte identifiers at the beginnings of files, but since any binary sequence can be regarded as a number, any feature of a file format which uniquely distinguishes it can be used for identification.

Your best bet is to store the file type along with the byte array.

You can try the magic number approach, but how could you know an html file from any other text file?

Comment: can you provide me a simple programmatical example, after your permission and massive thanks in advance

Comment: @XDev There is a library that could help: https://github.com/0xbrock/FileTypeChecker

Comment: Unfortunately this Library, not efficient, I tested it but it wasn't recognize .xlsx files

Comment: @XDev - xlsx is zipped xml. Therefore, you should try to unpack the archive and parse the xml.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov what is your suggestion

Comment: @XDev - 1. unzip. 2. parse xml. 3. check xml.